# Label in data list error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, html, sql, datalist

:)
i want access to data in any text in label when generated that base in sql
but i recive this error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

please help me
:(

```
                <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333">
                    <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <ItemStyle BackColor="#3b5998" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="40px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ProfilePicUrl") %>' Width="50px" />
                        <div class="name-holder">
                            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' 
                                CssClass="request-name"/>
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Add" />
                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Deny" />
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                </asp:DataList>
            </div>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FacebookConnectionString %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT FriendRequest. UserName, aspnet_Users.ProfilePicUrl FROM FriendRequest INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON FriendRequest.UserName = aspnet_Users.UserName WHERE (FriendRequest.FriendRequest = @FriendRequest)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="username" Name="FriendRequest" 
                        PropertyName="Text" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C#:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label UserNameLabel = (Label)DataList1.FindControl("UserNameLabel");
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Facebook;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [FriendRequest] SET [Friends]=(SELECT FriendRequest FROM [FriendRequest] WHERE UserName=@UserName1) WHERE UserName=@username", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Page.User.Identity.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName1", UserNameLabel.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What line throws the exception ? What is the stack trace ? Putting some more effort into your question will attract better answers - and frankly, this type of question ought to be solved with the debugger rather than being asked on StackOverflow. If you have difficulties solving the problem, you can ask a specific question about that.

Answer (score 0):

`UserNameLabel` is null, because `FindControl` will not work with dynamically generated controls (ie., from the DataList). How would you expect this to work when there are multiple rows in the DataList ?

A better way to do this would be to utilize the [`CommandArgument` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx) of the button to carry the necessary argument into your event handler. MSDN has an example on how to use that.

Comment: hi tanks for answer...If possible give me sample code that do it...i want insert firend name in cloum Firends that their name is equal UserNameLabel.text the number of requests is created...thanks

Answer (score 0):

remove extra space in FriendRequest.UserName and also once fire the query in your sql server and check for the UserName.

Comment: hi tanks for answer...If possible give me sample code that do it...i want insert firend name in cloum Firends that their name is equal UserNameLabel.text the number of requests is created...thanks